# Random Forest error non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, random-forest

I am following tutorial in R studio and I cannot compile code at
https://github.com/dataprofessor/rshiny_freecodecamp/blob/main/3-play-golf/app.R

Following line of code does not work and I do not get why. Please help.

```
model <- randomForest(play ~ ., data = weather, ntree = 500, mtry = 4, importance = TRUE)# Save model to RDS file
```

> Error in y - ymean : non-numeric argument to binary operator In
> addition: Warning messages: 1: In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
> The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want
> to do regression? 2: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or
> logical: returning NA

Comment: Did you try restarting your R environment and running the first part of that code (up until `model <- randomForest(...)` ? I assume it should work because it is published. Odds are you have been working interactively and have changed the `weather` data frame.

Comment: Well, the error says it all. Are you sure your data is made for regression? Because the model doesn't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being caught by the difference of how R 4.x0 and R3.x are treating the creation of data.frames. Before R4.x and when the above example was created, strings were automatically transformed into factors. This changed in R4.0 were the default is that strings are not converted to factors when creating a data.frame.

To solve your code:
Either set `stringsAsFactors` to `TRUE`

```
# Read data
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataprofessor/data/master/weather-weka.csv"
weather <- read.csv(file = url, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

# Build model
model <- randomForest(play ~ ., data = weather, ntree = 500, mtry = 4, importance = TRUE)
```

Or create a factor yourself:

```
# Read data
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataprofessor/data/master/weather-weka.csv"
weather <- read.csv(file = url)

weather$play <- as.factor(weather$play)

# Build model
model <- randomForest(play ~ ., data = weather, ntree = 500, mtry = 4, importance = TRUE)
```